# Remove/unset every other key in multidimensional array but preserve keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a long multidimensional array with timestamps as keys which contain arrays of values. Something like this but with more timestamps:

```
array(3) {
  [1502609400]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Item1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(100)
    }
    ["Item2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(50)
    }
  }
  [1502611200]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Item1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(200)
    }
    ["Item2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(150)
    }
  }
  [1502613000]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Item1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(500)
    }
    ["Item2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(250)
    }
  }
```

How can I remove every every second array of the array without losing the keys as timestamp? So I end up with this:

```
array(3) {
  [1502609400]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Item1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(100)
    }
    ["Item2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(50)
    }
  }
  [1502613000]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Item1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(500)
    }
    ["Item2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PRICE"]=>
      float(250)
    }
  }
```

If I use a for loop and unset every second key I lose all the keys and end up with 0, 1, 2 etc. instead of the timestamp.

Comment: In a loop, just check for index, and unset every second element:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a loop, check for index and unset every second element:

You can use custom `$index` variable, like this:

```
$index = 0; // points to first element

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($index % 2 != 0) { //check for un-even
        unset($array[$key]);
    }   

    $index++; // move pointer to next element
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but $key would be 1502611200 for example. So this wont work, since it's divisible by 2.

Comment: Added custom $index variable to maintain it separately, only purpose to find-out the even/odd elements.

Comment: Just wanted to say that too, as I combined your answer and @Osama 's :)
Thanks @M Idrees this works great! 

Marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i=1 // where the key to remove 
$x=0; //loop to determine the key position
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
if($x==$i){
unset($array[$key]);
}
$x++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly. Didn't think about adding a counter which makes a lot of sense.

* Edit: Sorry, this does not work with a longer array. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Why iterate over the entire array when all you want is modify the first element?

Comment: Depending on the same idea you can achieve that note the every second item must be 1,3,5,6 and the counter must be less than array count if you need help I can edit code or if you can do it by yourself

Comment: Thanks for the help, the count brought me up to the now correct answer by  @M-Idrees.

Answer (score 1):

In that kind of case, a simple foreach can be more efficient perfwise than a standard function :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (array_key_exists('Item2', $val)) {
        unset($val['Item2']);
    }
}
```